# How do I use some inputted text in a html form to query a SQLite database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

How do I use some inputted text in a html form to query a SQLite database?

Forgive me, I am very new to Ruby on Rails (couple of days).

I am getting a user to enter a number followed by enter, I then want to query my SQLite db and return results to a variable. I am working in a Ruby on Rails project. Here is the code in my home.html.erb file.

```
<form name="myform" action="" method="get">

  <input type="text" name="CardNumber" onkeypress="if(event.keyCode==13) {javascript:form.submit();>
    <input type="submit" onClick="javascript:form.submit();"/>
  <br>
</form>

<br>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
document.forms['myform'].elements['CardNumber'].focus();
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

First I think you'll want to do a `post` instead of a `get`. Then you need to point `action` to the correct route.

Usually in rails you'll have a model object instantiated on the action that renders the view with the form. Like if it's a form for creating a new User, on the controller#new action you'll have something like:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
```

then on the view you'll have `<%= form_for(@user) ... %>`
Since you instantiated @user, form_for will be able to render correctly the path and action when you give it that object as a parameter. It won't be able to figure out if it's a multipart or whatever else, but the basis of routing it will.

But you don't need it obviously. Going back to your sample.
Imagine you have a route

`post "save_payment_info", to: "payments#save_cc", as: :cc_save`

Then a controller:

```
payments_controller.rb

def save_cc
   cc_number_from_form = params[:CardNumber]
end
```

So you'll be able to access your form fields (as long as they're named correctly) on the `params` hash inside the controller.

You can do the same with Ajax and return a JSON response, etc.